# Excel Macro Duplicate / Sort

Tags: excel, vba

This is the macro i am using, it looks at a field (AS) and then depending on the number in that column it will create the same amount of rows underneath. So for example if AS has '4' it will create 4 rows containing the number 4.

I need an amendment to this so that these rows will show 1-4, 2-4, 3-4, 4-4

```
Sub addlabels()

Dim r As Long

For r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(r, "AS") > 1 Then
       Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Copy
       Cells(r + 1, 1).EntireRow.Resize(Cells(r, "AS").Value - 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Here is an example image of how i need the column to display at the moment it just simply copies from the top field https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8bl8.png

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try like this:
Considering the field("AS") is in cell a1 i've used the following code:

```
Sub addinglabels()
Dim i As Integer
cellvalue = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
If (cellvalue > 1) Then
For i = 1 To cellvalue
Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = i & "--" & cellvalue
Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is providing me with an error 400 could you explain the code at all.

Comment: Just an update to this, it's now working but its only looking at one field where as the original code looks at the entire column values - is this able to be amended

Comment: Its to check the entire column, if you run the orginal script and populate AS (or A1) with the number 5 as an example it will create 5 rows of that value.